# Converting java lambda to pre java 1.8 function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am using Babbler to write an XMPP soft client for doing load testing.

In the API documentation [Babbler documentation](http://sco0ter.bitbucket.org/babbler/basics.html), it mentions adding listeners to intercept incoming messages. However, the example code is written in lambda form.

```
// Listen for messages
xmppClient.addInboundMessageListener(e -> {
    Message message = e.getMessage();
    // Handle inbound message.
});
```

I need help converting this to Java 1.7 function since our load generation tool (nGrinder) does not support lambda syntax.

Comment: read the documentation provide by this platform. It have good reference. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions#t=201608220301237469302

Comment: Thank you for that. I will take time to go through the entire thing once I'm freed up. For the mean time, I need a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Listen for messages
xmppClient.addInboundMessageListener(new Consumer<MessageEvent>() {

    public void accept(MessageEvent e) { 
        Message message = e.getMessage();
        // Handle inbound message.
    }
});
```

You can also avoid creating a new Consumer instance every time you invoke a certain lambda function by storing it in an instance variable.

```
private Consumer<MessageEvent> inboundMessageListener;

//should be called during startup only
public void initialize() {
    inboundMessageListener = new Consumer<MessageEvent>() {

        public void accept(MessageEvent e) { 
            Message message = e.getMessage();
            // Handle inbound message.
        }
    };
}

//can be reused for more than one XMPP client, assuming there's no difference in handling different clients
public void addInboundMessageListener() {

    xmppClient.addInboundMessageListener(inboundMessageListener);
}
```

Comment: Adding the instance variable comment is really helpful and would speed things up if I'm receiving a lot of events.

Comment: @jeffsia: that doesn’t speed up anything. The code that is executed *when receiving an event* is exactly the same.

Comment: @Holger of course he's not going to call the `initialize()` method every time. The snippet is only a sample.

Comment: @Julio D: now it makes more sense, though scenarios like this are rather unlikely. Note, how this confused the OP into [thinking there was a difference when receiving an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070766/converting-java-lambda-to-pre-java-1-8-function#comment65490209_39070823) whereas it only make a difference when registering the listener multiple times to a source.

Comment: @Holger Point taken, it doesn't really matter though at this point as I only wanted the snippet for a few tests without taking performance as a consideration.

Answer (score 4):

Such a lambda is a just a shorthand for an anonymous implementation of a [functional] interface. You can always implement it yourself "the long way":

```
// Listen for messages
xmppClient.addInboundMessageListener(new Consumer<MessageEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(MessageEvent e) {
        Message message = e.getMessage();
        // Handle inbound message.
    }
});
```

Comment: Brief and concise. Thanks! Just what I needed.